# Python Pickle Problem - Output not matching with Hackerrank

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

I’m trying to solve the below question on Hackerrank.
[image: question]

It is working on Pycharm IDE but on Hackerrank the output is not matching with the expected output given. Below is the Code I used

```
import os
import builtins
import pickle
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit = 0
import traceback
import io
from logging import Logger

safe_builtins = {
    'range',
    'complex',
    'set',
    'frozenset'
}


class RestrictedUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        # Only allow safe classes from builtins.
        if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins:
            return getattr(builtins, name)
        # Forbid everything else.
        raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
                                     (module, name))


def restricted_loads(s):
    """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
    return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()


def func1(a):
    try:
        x = restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(a))
        return a
    except pickle.UnpicklingError:
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        return s


def func2(s):
    try:
        x = restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(slice(0, 8, 3)))
        return s[x]
    except pickle.UnpicklingError:
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        return s


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = range(int(input()))
    b = func1(a)
    print(b)
    y = tuple(input())
    z = func2(y)
    print(z)
```

Expected Output:

```
range(0, 50):
Traceback (most recent call last):
_pickle.UnpicklingError: global 'builtins.slice' is forbidden
```

Actual Output:

```
range(0, 50):
_pickle.UnpicklingError: global 'builtins.slice' is forbidden
```

Question: Why does the output not match in hackerrank when the code seems to be correct?

Answer (score 0):

This is an acceptable answer for Hackerrank. I included sys.stdout.write("Traceback (most recent call last):\n") since we declared the traceback=0 initially and pickle.UnpicklingError class doesn't have a traceback message. Try the below code for Hacker rank.

```
def func2(s):
  try:
      x = restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(slice(0, 8, 3)))
      return s[x] 
  except pickle.UnpicklingError as e :
      sys.stdout.write("Traceback (most recent call last):\n")
      s = traceback.format_exc()
    
      return s
```

PS: This is just an acceptable answer for Hackerrank. I just made simple modifications according to the output needs. This might not be a good practice everywhere. And I dont have full knowledge of it either.

```
import os
import builtins
import pickle
import sys
sys.tracebacklimit=0
import traceback
import io
from logging import Logger
safe_builtins = {
    'range',
    'complex',
    'set',
    'frozenset'
}


class RestrictedUnpickler(pickle.Unpickler):

    def find_class(self, module, name):
        # Only allow safe classes from builtins.
        if module == "builtins" and name in safe_builtins:
            return getattr(builtins, name)
        # Forbid everything else.
        raise pickle.UnpicklingError("global '%s.%s' is forbidden" %
                                     (module, name))


def restricted_loads(s):
    """Helper function analogous to pickle.loads()."""
    return RestrictedUnpickler(io.BytesIO(s)).load()


def func1(a):
    try:
        x = restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(a))
        return a
    except pickle.UnpicklingError:
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        
        return s


def func2(s):
    try:
        x = restricted_loads(pickle.dumps(slice(0, 8, 3)))
        return s[x] 
    except pickle.UnpicklingError as e :
        sys.stdout.write("Traceback (most recent call last):\n")
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        
        return s
        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = range(int(input()))
    b = func1(a)
    print(b)
    y = tuple(input())
    z = func2(y)
    print(z)
```